# Imported shapefiles will not load correctly in Android app MapIT

Tags: coordinate-system, android, mapit

I am able to import shapefiles created with ArcMap, but the features do not appear on my map.  When I zoom to them I am taken to the North Pole.  I assume this is a projection issue.

MapIT has a much more limited selection of projections, mostly European, than ArcMap and the programs do not share any.  I have tried reprojecting the .shp files created with ArcMap to similar projections available in MapIT to no avail.

For instance, I tried NAD1983 UTM to NAD1927 UTM which I assume is similar to EPSG UTM.  Running Android 7.1.2 (nougat) by the way.

Comment: `MapIT has a much more limited selection of projections,` ~ that seems to go against what is documented. You should be able to define any CRS as long as it has an EPSG code.  What EPSG codes did you try?

Comment: I tried EPSG codes 2023 and 2024

Comment: err 2024 and 2025